# knockoutjs 3.4 cannot apply binding to the same element again

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-3.0

i have a viewmodel associated with an index page with something like this

```
// html
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse js-navbar-collapse" id="menuholder">
<ul foreachbinding>
  <li binding>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="maincontent">
</div>
// javascript
        var VM = function () {
            var self = this;


            self.menuitems = ko.observableArray([]);
            self.loadmenu = function () {

                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: "/Home/GetMainMenu",
                    success: function (html) {
                        self.menuitems = html.menus


                    },
                    async: false
                });
            }
            self.loadmenu();
        };

ko.applyBindings(VM, document.getElementById("menuholder"));
```

as you can see i am appliying the binding only to the menuholder element .

now i load the content of the maincontent element dynamically with this :

```
$("#maincontent").load("pages/home.html");
```

the home.html page has it's own view model like this

```
//html
<body id="homepage">

</body>
//javascript
  var homeVM = function () {
            var self = this;
            self.topventes = ko.observableArray([]);
            self.promos = ko.observableArray([]);
            self.arrivage = ko.observableArray([]);
            self.nouveaute = ko.observableArray([]);
            self.loadcontent = function () {

                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: "/Home/GetHomePageContent",
                    success: function (html) {

                        self.topventes = html.topventes;
                        self.arrivage = html.arrivage;
                        self.nouveaute = html.nouveaute;
                        self.promos = html.promo;
                    },
                    async: false
                });
            }
            self.loadcontent();
        };

        ko.applyBindings(homeVM, document.getElementById("homepage"));
```

but at runtime i get the  **"cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element"** error .

any idea on what's going on please ?

Comment: What is this '#maincontainer', is it <div id="maincontent">
</div>?. This ko.applyBindings(homeVM, document.getElementById("homepage"));, you are trying to bind the <body> tag with your homeVM. I am not sure how you organize your html, binding the body tags also means binding to the whole document.

Comment: sorry for the confusion but i have made a little copy/paste mistake (fixed), maincontainer is the same as maincontent and this element is in the index page , i load dynamic content html page with jquery ajax within it .

Comment: ko.applyBindings(homeVM, document.getElementById("homepage")); is in the child page not in index , so the bound body is not the index page but from the dynamically loaded page

Comment: Can you try to change body tag to div tag?

Comment: this did the trick :) !

Comment: if so, please mark my answer below as correct :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root cause is your `home.html` has the body tag. It will cause KO to misunderstand the whole structure of the document. Anyway, you cannot put `body` tag in that view anyway.

Just change `body` tag to `div` tag, it should be fixed.